# Should image manipulation logic go in the Controller or the View?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

At the moment I have a zoom method in a View class which resizes an image being displayed.

Should this logic be in the View or inside the Controller ? Why so ?

Comment: Not in the controller. Because controller is responsible for altering the state of model layer and (in rare cases) current view. It is definitely **not responsible** for UI logic.

Comment: Although I am not a Swing dev, I suspect people able to answer this would be better in a position to do so if you can edit your zoom method and other relevant snippets into your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with putting it in the view is that the view in (at least some) web frameworks is implemented as little more than a template file and a mechanism to inject values into it. This doesn't feel like a suitable place in practice, since doing so would mix business logic with presentation, which in turn would defeat the purpose of using a framework in the first place.

If your application is re-rendering an image prior to outputting it, perhaps you could create a service class that carries out this function, and then call that from the controller. That way you avoid putting logic in your presentation layer, and you keep the resize logic separate from the web context of the controller, which increases testability.

Comment: Hmm, I've written this from the perspective of MVC-like _web_ applications, but have realised you've not specified whether this is a web or traditional GUI app. If you can clarify in your question (even better, explain what framework you are using) that might help attract more practical answers.

Comment: This is for desktop app. running in (Java) Swing.

Comment: Righto. I suspect my answer still holds, but I'm not a Java/Swing developer. You could wait for other answers to come in, or have a hunt for F/OSS Swing apps - there should be some good examples out there.

Comment: View is not a template. If you have a framework which insists otherwise, then **it has nothing to do with MVC**. Also, the question was **not** about resizing the physical image file.

Comment: @tereško, I understand your point regarding MVC, but your quarrel is with those implementations, and not with me. I find myself using the phrase "MVC-like" in relation to web frameworks of this kind, purism be damned - because OPs are more often looking for good-enough solutions than semantic discussions.

Comment: Notice the missing down-vote =P If I had a genuine issue with your answer, wouldn't think twice on paying a single rep-point or it.

Comment: The zoom logic has to be executed as a part of the JSlider change listener (part of the controller).  Where the zoom logic resides is up to you.

Comment: "perhaps you could create a service class that carries out this function, and then call that from the controller"

What if the zoom function has code that is highly dependant on Swing ?

Comment: I've not used Swing, but can your code do all its Swing operations on an instance of Swing? If so, pass in a Swing object to the service class, so that it remains testable. In order to encourage some Swing devs to answer, is there any code you can add to your question to give it a bit more substance?